# CSS not working in IE or Firefox - Chrome works fine

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

The webpage at 
    `http://144.76.221.141:8000`
is showing correct CSS styling in Chrome and Safari, but refuses to show in Firefox or Chrome. I have already seen that adding a doctype is a common fix for this, however this did not help at all with my problem. Any pointers to a solution would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: CSS, html?....fiddle?

Comment: Its just due different browser path rendering, webkit browsers like chrome, safari ignore but mozilla donot, so just remove first slash '/' in the path to css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type`on your stylesheets need to be like the following:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/parent.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="/css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="/css/dropit.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Removing the `/` at the begining.

Comment: So simple, sheesh! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Remove the slash in the type of your stylesheet declaration:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/parent.css" type="/text/css" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/parent.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For this declaration that links your CSS

```
<link href="/css/dropit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="/text/css"></link>
```

You need to remove the extra slash `/` on `type="/text/css"` should be

```
<link href="/css/dropit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write IE only CSS by adding this to your style sheet.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>...</style>
<![endif]-->
```

For further reference you can visit http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html